# Grabbing left side of comma in returned SQL result for JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table A joins to TABLE B on an ID. The problem I'm finding is that sometimes in table A, the returned column for ID is multiple ID's Separated by a comma. So what I'm trying to do is just to a join based on the 1st id in the CSV list.

```
SELECT ID, name
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TabelB b ON b.id = a.id
```

Also, please note that the ID's in both tables aren't primary key's. They are just named like that.

Here's what the content looks like in table A/B

```
Table A
ID           Name
10023,2019   Bob
1243         Mary
29853        William

Table B
Company      ID
Kroc         10023
Espres       99378
MarcDonalds  10023
etc...
```

In the supplied example data, only Kroc should come up with Bob. Even though there are 2 results in table B, just ignore and return 1.

Comment: You're going to need to split your id column by "," - there are plenty of examples of how to do that out there.

Comment: in a SQL statement?

Comment: BTW - you do realise SQL Server 2008 is so far out of support as to be dangerous? You should be seriously looking at upgrading asap.

Comment: unfortunately, right now that's out of my control 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there are already answers posted using `left`/`substring`, but I will note that you can probably also use a `like` if you prefer. Depending on your datatypes, something like the following will probably work (or it could be modified to account for your datatypes):

```
SELECT b.ID, name
FROM TableA a
 INNER JOIN TableB b
  ON a.id = b.id OR a.id like b.id + ',%'
```

You can see it [working in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1Q3a5ZBL). The idea is that it must either match exactly or match up to the first comma.

Comment: Just realized that Table B may have multiple of the same ID's. So in this example, it has 2 rows returned with the ID of 10023. How do I force it to return just 1 row back?

Comment: I awarded your comment because you met the original criteria. Love the solution actually. Didn't know you could do something like that. I created a new question for the new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990727/joining-2-tables-with-many-to-many-ids-but-returning-1-row

Answer (score 1):

You will need [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for that.

Something like that `ON b.id = SUBSTRING(a.id + ',', 1, CHARINDEX(',', a.id + ',') -1)`. You might also need explicit datatype casts.

But your tables do not follow 1NF. Maybe it is time to think, whether this is reasonable or not.

Comment: i tried putting something together with left and charindex but the problem now is if there is NO comma, i get an error. I'll try this example. Thank you.

Comment: @DaleK yes, you are right. not all of the ids are with comma. I'll edit my answer, thanks