# Joining 2 tables with many-to-many id's, but returning 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table A joins to TABLE B on an ID. Table A column sometimes has a csv of ID's. I'm only interested in the first ID for the join. The 2nd problem is that table B sometimes has the same ID multiple times. Again, I'm only interested in the first instance of the ID. The other rows can be ignored.

So ultimately my result should be 1 row per ID. Thanks to Stack Overflow, here's what I got for the table A CSV solution. The problem I'm left with now is returning 1 row from table b

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON b.id = a.id OR a.id LIKE b.id +',%'
```

Also, please note that the ID's in both tables aren't primary key's. They are just named like that.

Here's what the content looks like in table A/B

```
Table A
ID           Name
10023,2019   Bob
1243         Mary
29853        William

Table B
Company      ID
Kroc         10023
Espres       99378
MarcDonalds  10023
etc...
```

In the supplied example data, only Kroc should come up with Bob. Even though there are 2 results in table B, just ignore and return 1.

Comment: Showing your actual desired results would make the question much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `group by` and `max()` :

```
SELECT b.ID, max(name) as name
FROM TableA a
 INNER JOIN TableB b
  ON a.id = cast(b.id AS VARCHAR(10)) OR a.id like cast(b.id AS VARCHAR(10))  + ',%'
group by b.ID
```

I suppose the id in Table B integer this is way I converted it to `VARCHAR` to match with `a.id`

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/m_M_2PgL)

Comment: Wow. You are amazing. It's unbelievable how much knowledge there is out there and how little of it i know. Thank you!